# Can't Get Devise Emails to Use HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, devise

I'm using Rails 3.2.8 and Devise 2.0.4. I'm trying to get Devise emails to send using the 'https' protocol, but none of the solutions I can find are working.

I've already added this to my config/production.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'www.mysite.com', :protocol => 'https' }
```

And this to the top of the same file...

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

My NON-Devise emails are working correctly, but these settings appear to have no affect on the Devise emails. As a result, when the http  link is clicked in the email, my Apache server is redirecting to 'https' but the trailing slash is being removed and, thus, the url can't be found. I've tried adding a trailing slash on the Apache server, but that doesn't seem to work, either. I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this including the protocol in your `host` parameter:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'https://www.example.com' }
```

This works in Rails 5 and Devise 4, but you would have to test it in Rails 3.2